# Logism Signal Generator

Tags: software, simulation

I am using [Logisim](http://www.cburch.com/logisim/) and I can not work out how to make sine wave.
I have searched on google and can't find out how I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logisim is a digital simulator, it only supports 'on' and 'off'.  If you need to make a sine wave, then you can either make a sampled, quantized sinewave with a DDS (phase accumulator and lookup table) or you can get a SPICE simulator.